# How come when I try to run 2 python scripts that give and take data from another and one's reading serial port data I get a permission error?

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

So I have 2 python scripts, one is reading serial port data and the other is receiving a list from that data, however once I run the second script I get a permission error and can no longer read from the serial port. These are my 2 scripts and I'm doing stuff with Arduino, I know that I can have all this in 1 file but for latency purposes I separated the logic from the read. Here are my scripts:

read.py:

```
import serial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)

while True:

    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    decoded_bytes = ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode('utf-8')

    if len(decoded_bytes) == 0:
        ser.flushInput()
    if len(decoded_bytes) != 0:

        find1 = decoded_bytes.find('&')
        find2 = decoded_bytes.find('|')
        find3 = decoded_bytes.find('/')

        left = decoded_bytes[0:find1]
        right = decoded_bytes[find1+1:find2]
        fire = decoded_bytes[find2+1: find3]
        jump = decoded_bytes[find3+1:]

        keypresses = [left, right, fire, jump]

    ser.flushInput()
```

do.py:

```
from read import keypresses
import pyautogui as pg

while True:
    if keypresses[0] == 1:
        pg.keyDown('a')
    else:
        pg.keyUp('a')

    if keypresses[1] == 1:
        pg.keyDown('d')
    else:
        pg.keyUp('d')

    if keypresses[2] == 1:
        pg.mouseDown()
    else:
        pg.mouseUp()

    if keypresses[3] == 1:
        pg.keyDown('w')
    else:
        pg.keyUp('w')
```

If you could help that'd be nice, thanks.

Comment: What permission error? Please [edit] to include a traceback, and probably any details about the actual permissions on whatever resource it's complaining about.

Comment: How is one script feeing into the other?